# Images not found: Why does React claim the images are outside src folder when they are not?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, assets, webpack-dev-server

I recently switched to create-react-app as I had issues in production.

Now, I have this folder structure with the images being inside my asset folder which is inside my src folder:

[image]

At the top of my Main.js-file I seek to import my image files like so:

```
import Pic from "../assets/Aalto.png"
```

However, I get this error from devserver: "Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../assets/Aalto.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/."

-> this code worked flawlessly before my switch to create-react-app AND when trying to import "./Website_pic.jpg" instead (which you can see in the picture), which is not inside my asset folder, then the problem does not arise.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to go out of the `src` folder by using `..`

Change this

```
import Pic from "../assets/Aalto.png"
```

To this:

```
import Pic from "./assets/Aalto.png"
```

Comment: Oh, how silly of me ...